# Machine learning, best technique

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, svm

I'd like to know the best technique to learn for classifying pictures and audio. SVM does a decent job but takes a lot of time. Anyone know a faster and better one? Also I'd like to know the fastest library for SVM.

Comment: [image classification with decision trees](http://www.google.com/search?q=image+classification+with+decision+trees)

Comment: One approach for increasing the performance of the SVM is by preprocessing the raw data using k-means (or other clustering method) to reduce the amount of data being handled by the SVM.  You can convert the audio to spectral representation then cluster on the 3-space formed by (frequency,level,time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has to do with the state of the art of classification algorithms, as you say, the election of the classifier depends on your data, in the case of images, I can tell you that there is one method called Ada-Boost, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) and [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Eaz/lectures/cv/adaboost_matas.pdf) to know more about it, in the other hand, you can find lots of people are doing some researh, for example in [Gender Classification of Faces Using Adaboost](http://Gender%20Classification%20of%20Faces%20Using%20Adaboost%2077) [Rodrigo Verschae,Javier Ruiz-del-Solar and Mauricio Correa] they say:

> Adaboost-mLBP outperforms all other Adaboost-based methods, as well as baseline methods (SVM, PCA and PCA+SVM)

Take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll read it. DO you also happen to know a good libraby for SVM? i know SVMlight and libSVM. SVM light is faster.

Comment: I have used [weka][1] and it is a good `java` classiffication tool; see this [example][2] to run svm in weka


  [2]: http://www.stat.nctu.edu.tw/~misg/WekaInC.ppt


  [1]: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Comment: Thank you. I'll look through it. I'll wait one more day before accepting. I am waiting for more opinions. Thank you for yours.

Comment: Would preprocessing help, such as performing K-means clustering on the input, then presenting the clustered result to the SVM?

Comment: Commonly you start some algorithms in a random way, but if you do some kind of preprocessing it sould help a lot the algorithm, when you say clustering you mean unsupervised learning??, if you do, then you can use EM algorithm that can use k-means and then know how many `k` or classes you have and then let svm classify them

Comment: I just know K-means works really well in the image processing domain and I suspect it could be made to work in the audio domain as well by clustering in the 3-space formed by (frequency,level,time) where time is windowed to something suitable to the domain (voice recognition versus music recognition, etc.), allowing all three axes to be constriained to [0.0,1.0].  Well on a monaural channel anyways (though one could cluster in 4-space with an added pan=[0.0,1.0] where 0.5=center or even 5D to add front-rear).  K-mean the raw data first then submit only the clustered result to SVM.

Answer (score 2):

If your main concern is speed, you should probably take a look at [VW](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki) and generally at stochastic gradient descent based algorithms for training SVMs.

Answer (score 2):

if the number of features is large in comparison to the number of the trainning examples 
then you should go for logistic regression or SVM without kernel

if the number of features is small and the number of training examples is intermediate
then you should use SVN with gaussian kernel

is the number of features is small and the number of training examples is large 
use logistic regression or SVM without kernels .

that's according to the stanford ML-class .

Answer (score 1):

I think feature extraction and selection is important.

For image classification, there are a lot of features such as raw pixels, [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) feature, color, texture,etc. It would be better choose some suitable for your task.

I'm not familiar with audio classication, but there may be some specturm features, like the fourier transform of the signal, [MFCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum).

The methods used to classify is also important. Besides the methods in the question, KNN is a reasonable choice, too.

Actually, using what feature and method is closely related to the task.

Answer (score 1):

The method mostly depends on problem at hand. There is no method that is always the fastest for any problem. Having said that, you should also keep in mind that once you choose an algorithm for speed, you will start compromising on the accuracy.

For example- since your trying to classify images, there might a lot of features compared to the number of training samples at hand. In such cases, if you go for SVM with kernels, you could end up over fitting with the variance being too high.
So you would want to choose a method that has a high bias and low variance. Using logistic regression or linear SVM are some ways to do it.

You could also use different types of regularizations or techniques such as SVD to remove the features that do not contribute much to your output prediction and have only the most important ones. In other words, choose the features that have little or no correlation between them. Once you do this, you would be able to speed yup your SVM algorithms without sacrificing the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

there are some good techniques in learning machines such as, boosting and adaboost.
One method of classification is the boosting method. This method will iteratively manipulate data which will then be classified by a particular base classifier on each iteration, which in turn will build a classification model. Boosting uses weighting of each data in each iteration where its weight value will change according to the difficulty level of the data to be classified.
While the method adaBoost is one ensamble technique by using loss function exponential function to improve the accuracy of the prediction made.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very open ended, and "best classifier for images" will largely depend on the type of image you want to classify. But in general, I suggest you study convulutional neural networks ( CNN ) and transfer learning, currently these are the state of the art techniques for the problem.

check out pre-trained models of cnn based neural networks from pytorch or tensorflow

Related to images I suggest you also study pre-processing of images, pre-processing techniques are very important to highlight some feature of the image and improve the generalization of the classifier.